# List of query params with Flask request.args

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to pass comma separated query parameters to a Flask endpoint.

An example URI would be:

`localhost:3031/someresource#?status=1001,1002,1003`

Looking at the return of `request.args` or `request.args.getlist('status')` I see that I only get a string.

```
ipdb> pp request.args
ImmutableMultiDict([('status', '1001,1002,1003')])
ipdb> request.args.getlist('status')
['1001,1002,1003']
```

I know I can split the string by comma but that feels hacky. Is there a more idiomatic way to handle this in Flask? Or are my query params wrong format?

**Solution**
Since Flask does not directly support comma separated query params, I put this in in my base controller to support comma-separated or duplicate query params on all endpoints.

```
request_data = {}
params = request.args.getlist('status') or request.form.getlist('status')
if len(params) == 1 and ',' in params[0]:
    request_data['status'] = comma_separated_params_to_list(params[0])})
else:
    request_data['status'] = params
```

```
def comma_separated_params_to_list(param):
    result = []
    for val in param.split(','):
        if val:
            result.append(val)
    return result
```

Comment: AFAIK query parameters are only key/value pairs. I would split it. Another option is send the request body as json and parse in backend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you might want here:

```
request.args.to_dict(flat=False)
```

`flat` is True by default, so by setting it to False, you allow it to return a dict with values inside a list when there's more than one.

According to [to_dict](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.to_dict) documentation:

```
 to_dict(flat=True)

    Return the contents as regular dict. If flat is True
    the returned dict will only have the first item present, if flat is False
    all values will be returned as lists.
```

Answer (score 37):

The `flask` variant [`getlist`](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict.getlist.html) expects multiple keys:

```py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def status():
    first_status = request.args.get("status")
    statuses = request.args.getlist("status")
    return "First Status: '{}'\nAll Statuses: '{}'".format(first_status, statuses)
```

```
❯ curl "http://localhost:5000?status=5&status=7"
First Status: '5'
All Statuses: '['5', '7']'
```

There's no standard for this, how multiple GET args are parsed/passed depends on which language/framework you're using; flask is built on [werkzeug](https://palletsprojects.com/p/werkzeug/) so it allows this style, but you'll have to look it up if you switch away from flask.

As an aside, Its not uncommon REST API design to have commas to pass multiple values for the same key - makes it easier for the user. You're parsing GET args anyway, parsing a resulting string is not that much more hacky. You can choose to raise a [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) HTTP error if their string with commas isn't well formatted.

Some other languages (notably PHP) support 'array' syntax, so that is used sometimes:

`/request?status[]=1000&status[]=1001&status[]=1002`

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna load a stringified array too:

```
def safe_load_args(request_args):
    """
    load stringified json values from request args
    replace single quotes with double quotes
    do not change value if value throws an error
    """
    for key, value in request_args.items():
        try:
            request_args[key] = json.loads(value.replace("'", '"'))
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return request_args
```

this can deal with

localhost:3031/someresource#?status=[1001,1002,1003]

```
request_args = safe_load_args(request.args.to_dict())
```

the value for status will be a string, "[1001,1002,1003]", which json.loads() can turn into a regular array.

This also works for a list of strings, but you'll have to put them in quotes, otherwise json.loads() will throw an exception (and leave the value unchanged)

localhost:3031/someresource#?status=["abc","def"]