# Pass a list type URL Argument in flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to pass a list as URL argument

```
@app.route('/getdata',defaults ={'my_list':['a','b']}, methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/getdata/<my_list>', methods=['GET'])
def getdata(my_list):
    pass
```

I am getting this error when i run it

```
TypeError: 'Response' object is not iterable
```

Comment: This can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/57914827/6849682

Comment: It is not recommended to pass a list in GET request, you should do it using post.